# Save Dynamic Array of textboxes

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jform

I have developed a code to create dynamic textboxes on click of "Add" button using javascript -

**Javascript**

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value,index) {
    return
     '<input type="text" name="jform[options][]" id="jform_options_'+index+'" value="">' +
       '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove btn-danger" />'
}
```

**formname.xml**

```
<field name="options][" type="text" label="Options" multiple="true" description=""></field>
```

When I click on Add button , it will append n number of textboxes . 
But I am facing a problem in saving this field in database.

**database**

```
columnname = options, type= text
```

I want to save the values entered in textboxes in form of json. For this I am trying to override the controller save method-

**controllername.php**

```
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null){

    if($_POST['jform']){
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $postData = $jinput->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');
            $postData['options']=json_encode(implode(',',$postData['options'])); 
        // Save it back to the $_POST global variable
        JRequest::setVar('jform', $postData, 'post');
    }
    // Finally, save the processed form data
    return parent::save('id', $urlVar);
}
```

But all the rest values in the form are saving but not the "options field."
- Note: you can see the image attached to understand what i am trying to achieve[image]

- Any help would be appreicated

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using prepareTable in the model of your component.
Check this **example** out where I get an the values of array of checkboxes "categories" and then save them creating a comma separated values variable using implode.

Instead of course, you may use json_encode.

```
protected function prepareTable($table)
{
    // Set the publish date to now
    $db = $this->getDbo();

    if($table->id==0)
    {
        $table->created = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();
    }

    $table->modified = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();

    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;


    $categories = $jinput->get('categories',null,'ARRAY');

    if($categories!=null)
        $table->categories = implode(",",$categories);
    else 
        $table->categories ='';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must save options as array json in database so change this line

```
  $postData['options']=json_encode(implode(',',$postData['options']));
```

to

```
  $postData['options']=json_encode($postData['options']);
```

then in loadFormData method in your model , you need to use json_decode for decode your array

also you can use [Repeatable field](https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type) type for your form , and if you set name of your field as params , the all the jobs will be handled by joomla